# GWTP ant build.xml - No processor claimed any of these annotations

Tags: gwt, ant, javac, gwt-platform, gwtp

I am trying to write the build.xml for a GWTP+MGWT project for mobile, desktop & tablet.

```
<property name="in.src.folder" location="src" />
<property name="apt_generated" location=".apt_generated" />
<property name="out.classes.folder" location="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
<property name="warlib.folder" location="war/WEB-INF/lib" />

<target name="javac" depends="cleanwar,libs" description="Compile java source to bytecode">
        <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" />

        <javac srcdir="${apt_generated}" destdir="${out.classes.folder}" includeantruntime="true" source="1.6" target="1.6" nowarn="false" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" >
            <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
             <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${in.src.folder}" includes="**" encoding="utf-8" destdir="${out.classes.folder}" source="1.6" target="1.6" nowarn="false" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="true">
            <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
             <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
        </javac>    
        <copy todir="${out.classes.folder}">
            <fileset dir="${in.src.folder}" includes="**/*.class" />
        </copy>
        <delete dir="${in.src.folder}" includes="**/*.class" failonerror="false" />
</target>
```

The application runs fine in dev mode and until now i can build it upto the javac target but i see these warnings-

No processor claimed any of these annotations:

com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.RequestTabs, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.NameToken, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ChangeTab, com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.SafeHtmlTemplates.Template, com.google.inject.Inject, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.TabInfo, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ProxyCodeSplit, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ContentSlot, com.google.inject.BindingAnnotation, com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler, com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath, com.google.gwt.inject.client.GinModules, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ProxyEvent, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.UseGatekeeper, com.synopsys.iims.fe.client.place.DefaultPlace, com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField, com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ProxyStandard

How can i resolve these? I believe these might be causing problems for gwtc target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These annotations don't have processors (they're processed by GWT generators), so you can safely ignore the warnings.